# How to add link to date of blog post in Blogger

Tags: blogger

I am trying to remove links from the title of my blog and add them to the date. I added the following lines to my template in Blogger to insert the URL of a post in the place I want.

```
<BlogItemTitle>
<BlogItemURL>
<a href="<$BlogItemURL$>">
</BlogItemURL>
<$BlogItemTitle$></a>
</BlogItemTitle>
```

However, it is not working as intended. It gives me an error and I can not figure out why. I have found these information here: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42095?hl=en

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more familiar with the template of your blog. Are you still struggling with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add something like this:

```
<a expr:href='data:post.url'>custom title here</a>
```